# WebScrapping running automatically 2 times a day - Python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've created a simple webScrapper that gets some information from CNN website and puts it into a database table.
Its working properly in Python and I'm using VScode.
I am looking for a way to run this script 2 times a day automatically, anyone knows how to do it? I tried AWS but I was not able to do it!

I want to run the code automatically online, with my computer off and it has to update my CSV file.

Some important information:

- Considering that it is a webScrapper I have some files that I have to use in my folders such as chromedriver.exe and a CSV that append the new roll with new information.
- Here is my code:

imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import yfinance as yf
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pyodbc
```

WebScrapping code:

```
dataset.to_csv(r"C:\Users\belig\OneDrive\Python\MeuProjeto\Projetos\WebScrapping_News\WebScrapping_News\dataset.csv", index=False)

dataset = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\belig\OneDrive\Python\MeuProjeto\Projetos\WebScrapping_News\WebScrapping_News\dataset_news.csv", sep=";")


# Creating Variables

# %%
Date = 1
WeekDay = 2
Brazil_Ibovespa = 3
BRL_Dollar = 4
Titulo_CNNBrasil = 5

# Setup Date Var

Date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
Date

# Setup WeekDay Var

date_now = datetime.now()
WeekDay = date_now.strftime("%A")
WeekDay

# Setup Brazil_Ibovespa Var

today = date.today()
start_day = today - timedelta(days = 7)
tickers_DowJones = "^BVSP"
datayf = yf.download(tickers_DowJones, start=start_day, end=today)
print(datayf)
datayf = datayf['Adj Close']

Brazil_Ibovespa = datayf[-1]
Brazil_Ibovespa

# Setup BRL_Dollar Var

requisicao = requests.get('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/all/USD-BRL')
cotacao = requisicao.json()
BRL_Dollar = round(float(cotacao['USD']['bid']),2)
BRL_Dollar

# Starting Driver WebScrapping (option to hide windown)

driver_exe = r'C:\Users\belig\OneDrive\Python\MeuProjeto\Projetos\WebScrapping_News\WebScrapping_News\chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_exe, options=options)


# Setup Titulo_CNNBrasil Var

driver.get('https://www.cnnbrasil.com.br/')
Titulo_CNNBrasil = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="block1847327"]/div/div/a/h2').text
print(Titulo_CNNBrasil)

# Setup Url_CNNBrasil Var

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="block1847327"]/div/div/a/h2').click()
Url_CNNBrasil = driver.current_url
print(Url_CNNBrasil)

# Setup Topics_CNNBrasil Var

try:
    Topics_CNNBrasil =  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tags__list').text
    Topics_CNNBrasil = Topics_CNNBrasil.replace('\n', ', ')
    print(Topics_CNNBrasil)
except:
    Topics_CNNBrasil = 'None'
    print
```

Add to SQL and DataFrame:

```
# Add Row to DataFrame

new_row = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[Date], "WeekDay":[WeekDay], "Brazil_Ibovespa":[Brazil_Ibovespa], "BRL_Dollar":[BRL_Dollar], "Titulo_CNNBrasil":[Titulo_CNNBrasil], "Url_CNNBrasil":[Url_CNNBrasil], "Topics_CNNBrasil":[Topics_CNNBrasil], index=[0])
print(new_row)
dataset = pd.concat([dataset, new_row], ignore_index=True)
# dataset = dataset.append({"Date":Date, "WeekDay": WeekDay}, ignore_index=True)
print(dataset)

dataset.to_csv(r'C:\Users\belig\OneDrive\Python\MeuProjeto\Projetos\WebScrapping_News\WebScrapping_News\dataset_news.csv', index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig", sep = ';')

# Add info to SQL Server

dados_conexao = (
    "Driver={SQL Server};"
    "Server=Beligolli;"
    "Database=WebScrappingNews;"
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    # UID  = Login;
    # PWD=Senha;
)


conexao = pyodbc.connect(dados_conexao)
cursor = conexao.cursor()

comando = "INSERT INTO NewsDataBase (Date_Hour, WeekDay_, Brazil_Ibovespa, BRL_Dollar, Titulo_CNNBrasil, Url_CNNBrasil, Topics_CNNBrasil VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

valores = (Date, WeekDay, Brazil_Ibovespa, BRL_Dollar, Titulo_CNNBrasil, Url_CNNBrasil, Topics_CNNBrasil)

cursor.execute(comando, valores)
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
conexao.close()

print(f'Adicionado {Date} - {WeekDay} ao dataset')
```

Answer (score 1):

First i start with this [library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/) to schedule the events:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and then save the script and if you want to run the app as a [windows service](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunPythonScriptAsAService.html)